How to use vgg16 model to train an classification AI (21 classes)
I'm a beginner at AI training and I'm trying to classify 2100 images from a 5 fold dataset using vgg16 model. The images are divided into 21 classes, each containing 100 samples. I followed a notebook from Saeki (https://www.kaggle.com/code/saekiryosuke/fine-tuned-classifier-with-vgg16-and-pytorch/notebook).
After separating the folds, training and testing into different directories (e.g. 'dataset/fold1/training/train00.tif'), I used this function to create the dataset:
CREATING DATASET AND LOADING MODEL:
class lungDataset(data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, file_list, transform=None, phase='training'):
        self.file_list = file_list
        self.transform = transform
        self.phase = phase

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.file_list)

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        # load image
        img_path = self.file_list[index]
        
        img_originalsize = Image.open(img_path)
        # resize
        img = img_originalsize.resize((256, 256))
        
        # color -> grey -> color
        img = img.convert("L").convert("RGB")

        # preprocess
        img_transformed = self.transform(
            img, self.phase)  # torch.Size([3, 224, 224])

        # picking up labels
        if img_path[74:77] == "tra":
            label = img_path[94:99]
            # print(label_a)
            label = int(int(label[:(label.find('.'))])/80)

        elif img_path[74:77] == "tes":
            label = img_path[92:97]
            # print(label_a)
            label = int(int(label[:(label.find('.'))])/20)
        # label img -> class
        

        return img_transformed, label

(The labeling method works because the dataset hadn't been shuffled before.)
Then, I used it like this, as according to the notebook from Saeki.
train_dataset = []
test_dataset = []

for k in range(k_fold_count):
  train_dataset.append(lungDataset(
      file_list=train_list[k], transform=ImageTransform(256, all_means[k], all_std[k]), phase='train'))

  test_dataset.append(lungDataset(
      file_list=test_list[k], transform=ImageTransform(256, all_means[k], all_std[k]), phase='test'))

And then I loaded my data using DataLoader (although I didn't fully understand what it does, I'd appreciate explanations).
train_dataloader = []
test_dataloader = []
dataloaders_dict = []

batch_size = 7
n_epochs = 200
baches_per_epoch = 21

for k in range(k_fold_count):

  # Loading train and test
  train_dataloader.append(torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
      train_dataset[k], batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True))
  test_dataloader.append(torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
      test_dataset[k], batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False))
  
  # This organizes the dataloading into 5 dictioneries
  # Each following the [train] and [test] keys
  dataloaders_dict.append({
    "train": train_dataloader[k],
    "test": test_dataloader[k]
    })

Then I loaded the vgg16 model, but I don't know what exactly to do after this and if what I did is correctly (it mostly makes sense to me).
# load pretrained vgg16 from PyTorch as an instance
# need to make setting 'internet' to 'On'.
use_pretrained = False
vgg16_net = models.vgg16(pretrained=use_pretrained)

# Replace output layer for 21 class classifier, 0 - 20
vgg16_net.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=21)


vgg16_net.train()

WHAT I TRIED:
I already tried following Saeki's notebook and doing
# setting of loss function
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# setting fine tuned parameters

params_to_update_1 = []
params_to_update_2 = []
params_to_update_3 = []

# Not only output layer, "features" layers and other classifier layers are tuned.
update_param_names_1 = ["features"]
update_param_names_2 = ["classifier.0.weight",
                        "classifier.0.bias", "classifier.3.weight", "classifier.3.bias"]
update_param_names_3 = ["classifier.6.weight", "classifier.6.bias"]

# store parameters in list
for name, param in vgg16_net.named_parameters():
    if update_param_names_1[0] in name:
        param.requires_grad = True
        params_to_update_1.append(param)
        #print("params_to_update_1:", name)

    elif name in update_param_names_2:
        param.requires_grad = True
        params_to_update_2.append(param)
        #print("params_to_update_2:", name)

    elif name in update_param_names_3:
        param.requires_grad = True
        params_to_update_3.append(param)
        #print("params_to_update_3:", name)

    else:
        param.requires_grad = False
        #print("no learning", name)

# print("-----------")
# print(params_to_update_1)

# Learning Rates
optimizer = optim.SGD([
    {'params': params_to_update_1, 'lr': 1e-4},
    {'params': params_to_update_2, 'lr': 5e-4},
    {'params': params_to_update_3, 'lr': 1e-3}
], momentum=0.9)

Followed by
def train_model(net, dataloaders_dict, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs):
    
    accuracy_list = []
    loss_list = []
    
    # Precondition : Accelerator GPU -> 'On'
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    print("using device：", device)

    # put betwork into GPU
    net.to(device)
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True

    # epoch loop
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs))
        print('-------------')

        for phase in ['train', 'test']:
            if phase == 'train':
                net.train()  # set network 'train' mode
            else:
                net.eval()   # set network 'val' mode

            epoch_loss = 0.0
            epoch_corrects = 0

            # Before training
            if (epoch == 0) and (phase == 'train'):
                continue
            
                      
            # batch loop
            for inputs, labels in tqdm(dataloaders_dict[phase]):
                   
                # send data to GPU
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)
                
                # initialize optimizer
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # forward
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    outputs = net(inputs)

                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)  #calcurate loss
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)  # predict
  
                    # back propagtion
                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                    # update loss summation
                    epoch_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)  
                    # update correct prediction summation
                    epoch_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)

            # loss and accuracy for each epoch loop
            epoch_loss = epoch_loss / len(dataloaders_dict[phase].dataset)
            epoch_acc = epoch_corrects.double(
            ) / len(dataloaders_dict[phase].dataset)
            
            print('{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(
                phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))
            
            if phase == 'val':
                accuracy_list.append(epoch_acc.item())
                loss_list.append(epoch_loss)
            
    return accuracy_list, loss_list

And
num_epochs=10

accuracy_list = []
loss_list = []

for k in range(k_fold_count):
  print(('-'*5) + f'Fold {k+1}' + ('-'*5))
  aux1, aux2 = train_model(
      vgg16_net,
      dataloaders_dict[k],
      criterion, optimizer,
      num_epochs=num_epochs
      )
  
  accuracy_list.append(aux1)
  loss_list.append(aux2)

But it outputs an error without finishing training: 'IndexError: Target 14 is out of bounds.' (the target number changed during the times I've ran the code).
What should I do in order to train the vgg16 without setting pretrained weights and to keep track of the loss function? I understand the theory but I'm lacking application.

Provide the full error backtrace.
